# Having some problems printing out an array in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that gets an array from a basic api on my website and spits it out as text.

This is the function...

```
def avDates() :

import urllib.request
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.website.com/api.php')
content = response.read()   
data = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
dates = []
for i in data:
    print(str(i['Month'])+": "+str(i['the_days']))


return dates
```

and this outputs this...

```
>>> 
Apr: 16, 29, 30
May: 13, 27
Jun: 10, 11, 24
Jul: 08, 22, 23
Aug: 06, 20
Sep: 02, 03, 16, 17, 30
Oct: 01, 14, 15, 29
Nov: 25
Dec: 09, 10, 23, 24
>>>
```

All I want to do is print out the following..

```
These are the dates: -
Apr: 16, 29, 30
May: 13, 27
Jun: 10, 11, 24
Jul: 08, 22, 23
Aug: 06, 20
Sep: 02, 03, 16, 17, 30
Oct: 01, 14, 15, 29
Nov: 25
Dec: 09, 10, 23, 24
```

In order that I can put them into a text or html based email script.

I've been through many combinations of %s and str() and format() but I can't seem to get the correct result.

If I do this...

```
from  availableDates import avDates
printTest = avDates()
print ("These are the dates - %s" % ', '.join(map(str, printTest)))
```

I get this...

```
Apr: 16, 29, 30
May: 13, 27
Jun: 10, 11, 24
Jul: 08, 22, 23
Aug: 06, 20
Sep: 02, 03, 16, 17, 30
Oct: 01, 14, 15, 29
Nov: 25
Dec: 09, 10, 23, 24
These are the dates: -
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working - just trying to learn.

Comment: But, does the 'print' line look as if it's the wrong way around?

Comment: Strangely, if I comment out the 'Print' line leaving only the import and variable declaration - the array still gets printed to the shell. So, I think, in my results above, the array gets printed from the printTest line and then doesn't get printed in the print line. Is there something wrong in the function definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your execution, you have the following:

```
from  availableDates import avDates
printTest = avDates()
print ("These are the dates - %s" % ', '.join(map(str, printTest)))
```

But in the `avDates()`, you already print the month one by one:

```
for i in data:
    print(str(i['Month'])+": "+str(i['the_days']))
```

In addition, your `dates` in the `avDates()` is an empty list, you initialize it:

```
dates = []
```

but never fill it with anything. Thus in your execution you got:

```
Apr: 16, 29, 30
May: 13, 27
Jun: 10, 11, 24
Jul: 08, 22, 23
Aug: 06, 20
Sep: 02, 03, 16, 17, 30
Oct: 01, 14, 15, 29
Nov: 25
Dec: 09, 10, 23, 24
```

from `avDates` ***and then***

```
These are the dates: -
```

From your last print where your `printTest` is an empty list.

In order to make it right, you should put up your `string` in the `dates` instead of printing it and return the `dates`:

```
def avDates() :

    import urllib.request
    import json

    response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.website.com/api.php')
    content = response.read()   
    data = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
    dates = []
    for i in data:
        dates.append(str(i['Month'])+": "+str(i['the_days'])) #don't print it yet               
    return dates
```

And then in the execution:

```
from  availableDates import avDates
printTest = avDates()
print ("These are the dates - ")
for pt in printTest:
    print (pt)
```

Then you should get what you expect:

```
These are the dates: -
Apr: 16, 29, 30
May: 13, 27
Jun: 10, 11, 24
Jul: 08, 22, 23
Aug: 06, 20
Sep: 02, 03, 16, 17, 30
Oct: 01, 14, 15, 29
Nov: 25
Dec: 09, 10, 23, 24
```

Comment: This works great - and a really helpful explanation! thanks for your help!!

Comment: @dazzathedrummer no problem! ;)